# Finding Q for filters

Tags: filter, transfer-function, resonance

Given the transfer function for a given filter, how can I find a value for the q-factor?

For example, I have this transfer function for a Sallen-Key lowpass filter

\$ H(s) = \dfrac{1}{R_1R_2C_1C_2s^2 + (R_1C_2 + R_2C_2)s + 1} \$

And I also have my component values. Now I've seen formulas for calculate Q from component values, but where do the formulas come from? Is there a way of finding Q from any transfer function?

Comment: A diagram showing R1,R2,C1,C2, would have been helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula you have corresponds (once rearranged) to a 2nd order low pass filter: -

\$ H(s) = \dfrac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + (2\zeta\omega_n)s + \omega_n^2} \$

So divide thru by \$ R_1R_2C_1C_2\$ and then you have all the bits in place.

You'll be able to see what \$\omega_n\$ is - the last term in the denomitor is \$\omega_n^2\$. The zeta (\$\zeta\$) symbol is the reciprocal of 2Q. So take the 2nd term in the denominator and divide it by \$\omega_n\$ and then rearrange to find Q.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm guessing for higher order filters you just find the standard transfer function, rearrange to that, then find \$ \omega_n \$ and \$ Q \$, right? Thanks again!

Comment: Higher order filters can only sensibly computed as individual 2nd order filters for the main reason that each filter would likely have different resonant frequencies and vastly different Q factors.

Comment: If you look up the theory behind the famous butterworth filter, each 2nd stage of a multi stage filter has different Q and Wn so there is no benefit to trying to congregate all these numbers into one entity.

Comment: It would have been very nice to see the actual answer, especially since it doesn't make any sense to just "divide thru"